# Slow UrlFetch on google app engine with Laravel 4.2

Tags: php, google-app-engine, symfony, laravel-4, urlfetch

I use Laravel 4.2 with Google App Engine. I followed [a tutorial](https://gae-php-tips.appspot.com/2013/10/22/getting-started-with-laravel-on-php-for-app-engine/) to run Laravel with gae, and on my gae development server (a VPS with the development SDK 1.9.22) everything works fine and fast. However, since I deployed my code in production, everything works but I note in the trace log that UrlFetch are very slow compared to the developement mode.

Indeed, the bucket is called a lot because Laravel needs some of its files to run, but each call is (very) slow. Google explains [how to make Symfony run on gae](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/symfony-hello-world), and says to use its own bucket instead of the file system as they don't provide access to it.

You can see in this trace log (i.stack.imgur.com/0aetT.png) that each urlFetch is slow (950+ms sometimes) to access a file, transforming a query that lasted barely 1s on my VPS into a query of 4s sometimes in production...

Does anyone know how to improve this ?

Thanks
Alex

Comment: Have you tried turning on optimistic caching as per https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/googlestorage/advanced#cached_file_reads?

Comment: @Mars Thanks for your help ! I tried turning on optimistic caching and I've observed improvements on files that i wanted the GCS url or to serve directly. However, for example, when Laravel calls the file_exists() php function for a file, urlFetch makes a HEAD request on the file, and if the response is a 404 error, the UrlFetch tries to search it. For example, Laravel checks if a "down" file exists (to set the website under maintenance). As the file doesn't exist, UrlFetch seems to perform a research of the file. You can see that in the trace log : [link](http://i.stack.imgur.com/e7XfB.jpg)

Comment: Unfortunately due to GCS's implementation, we're force to do an extra search after head to determine if the file/directory truly exists.

Comment: I understand but the time it takes is too long. A HEAD takes 200/300ms, and the following GET takes 200/300ms also... So to get/check a file It takes 400/600ms. It's too long for just one file in production... :/ Is that other people have the same problem with GAE and GCS ?

Comment: I have had the same problems for days now, resulting in stopping to program on my desktop. It works fine on my Linux tho. Have you had any revelations concerning this issue ?